# how to pass parameter to jake task like that namespace:task parameter?

Tags: node.js, namespaces, task, jake

I would like to have generators for my migration like:

`jake migration:create <name>`

`jake migration:remove <name>`

`jake migration:execute <name>`

code is

```
namespace('migration', function(){
  desc('Create migration file');
  task('create', [], function(params) {
    console.log(arguments);
    //some code for creation
  });

  desc('Remove migration file');
  task('remove', [], function(params) {
    console.log(arguments);
    //some code for removing
  });

  desc('Execute migration file');
  task('execute', [], function(params) {
    console.log(arguments);
    //some code for executing
  });

});
```

but I didn't find how to pass parameter `<name>` inside 'namespaced' jake task.
Could you please help me?

UPD:
even examples from https://github.com/isaacs/node-jake "Passing parameters to jake" doesn't work for me, every time `arguments` is empty,
any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

You should check: https://github.com/mde/jake

You pass parameters as comma separated list:

jake migration:create[run,foo,bar]

and then catch them in you function as params:

```
namespace('migration', function(){
    desc('Create migration file');
    task('create', [], function(p1,p2,p3) {
        console.log(p1,p2,p3);
        //some code for creation
  });

  desc('Remove migration file');
  task('remove', [], function(p1,p2,p3) {
    console.log(p1,p2,p3);
    //some code for removing
  });

  desc('Execute migration file');
  task('execute', [], function(p1,p2,p3) {
    console.log(p1,p2,p3);
    //some code for executing
  });

});
```